# Descargar archivo HTML

Tags: html

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando que un único botón de mi "web" descargue un archivo que tengo en el ordenador. De momento seria de forma local. Así lo tengo:

`<div class="mbr-section-btn align-left"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary display-4" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\Descarga">Descargar</a></div>`

Imagino que es por la ruta... Pero al pulsar en el me redirige aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero mi idea es que lo descargue automáticamente al dar click en el botón. ¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No seria: `href="C:\xampp\htdocs\Descarga\Generador.apk"`

Comment: Si **Descarga** es el archivo que quieres descargar, te falta indicar la extensión. Si no la indicas se piensa que estás queriendo acceder a un directorio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos cosas.

En primer lugar, estas apuntando a la carpeta que contiene un archivo, que imagino que es el que deseas descargar. Por ende, debes hacer lo que Orlando De La Rosa te indica que es apuntarlo correctamente.

En segundo lugar, si deseas descargarlo agrégale al tag el atributo download.
Así:

```
<div class="mbr-section-btn align-left"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary display-4" href="C:\xampp\htdocs\Descarga\Generador.apk" download>Descargar</a></div>
```

En tercer lugar, te recomiendo utilizar una ruta relativa a tu proyecto para cuando lleves el desarrollo a producción los vínculos te queden correctamente colocados.